# CGAffineTransform rotation and resize on slider value

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, uislider, cgaffinetransform

I am using `Slider` to `Resize` and `Rotate`-

For the Rotate -

```
 CGAffineTransform transform = editingView.transform;
  transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(sliderVal * 2*M_PI / 30);
  editingView.transform = transform;
```

For the Resize-

```
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sliderVal/30, sliderVal/30);
  CGPoint center = editingView.center; 
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                   animations:^{
                      editingView.transform = t;
                     editingView.center = center;
                   }
                   completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                   }];
```

Using the above code,Both working fine separately.

But I have to `resize` the rotated view,Or rotate the resized view.

I saw many suggestions coming separate behavior  because i am using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`,`CGAffineTransformMakeScale`,If i use the `CGAffineTransformScale`,`CGAffineTransformRotation` then my problem will be solve.

The problem is when I am using `CGAffineTransform` then scaling is not proper,`View` disappears from the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting transformation matrix of the view with `editingView.transform` line.

You should change your code for rotate:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = editingView.transform;
transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(sliderVal * 2*M_PI / 30);
editingView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(editingView.transform, transform);
```

and for resize:

```
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sliderVal/30, sliderVal/30);
CGPoint center = editingView.center; 
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                   animations:^{
                      editingView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(editingView.transform,t);
                      editingView.center = center;
                   }
                   completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                   }];
```

With `CGAffineTransformConcat` you add 2 transform matrixes together so you won't lose older transforms. You can use `CGAffineTransformIdentity` to reset the transform.

Answer (score 3):

```
        CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(self.webView.frame.origin.x,self.webView.frame.origin.y - self.webView.frame.size.height * 0.25);
        CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6);
        CGAffineTransform transform =  CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, degreesToRadians(-10));

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveAndRotateAnimation" context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut]; 
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];

            editingView.transform = transform;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Try like this...

Comment: @ArunSharma  for me it is working fine can u post your updated code

Comment: In your code sample you are doing both at the same time Scale and rotate,I have to do separately(Using two diffrent slider value) as i mentioned in my question.